# Reference material for calculating response times

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ios, delay

I have a mobile application (iOS) that sends instructions via a Comet server ([APE](http://www.ape-project.com/)) to a web application (JS). For each instruction, the web application responds with an "ack" message, tagged with the instruction id. What I want is to calculate the average response time for the web application.

The frequency of instructions may vary from 5 per second to on every other second (or even longer, depending on the user).

My naive solution is to timestamp each send and receive and then calculate the average among the differences. This is very inefficient since the algorithm (basic for-loop) stalls the application and inflicts a delay in handling the acks. Another solution is to use the ten latest timestamps and thus limiting the number of response times for the calculation.

I'm however not happy with this solution and am looking for some reference material that could provide me any information about the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: I don't see what's inefficient about what you're doing - unless you're trying to calculate an average on every single response, every time you get a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i use, not based on any scientific material, but works for me...

We keep the average of the **last** 10 + we keep the **worst** 2 **ever** and the **best** 2 **ever**.
We don't persist any data, so the worst/best 'ever' are measured since the reboot of the application server.

Then we make the average over these 14.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It definitely would have. The problem is no longer relevant, since I finished the project about 16 months ago. However, I'll keep your algorithm in mind.